# passing python variable into shell script

Tags: awk, python

Here is my script:

```
cmd=(''' ssh $servername /usr/local/bin/pstat $1|awk 'FNR==5 {print $9}' %s ''' %int(var))  
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)  
out, err=p.communicate()  
print "err", err
```

Here is the error:

`err awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file (No such file or directory)`

I believe I am not writing `cmd` properly. What am I missing?

Comment: What would the `cmd` string, tuple, whatever, be when you use it in `Popen()`? I'm not a Python programmer.

Comment: `cmd` output from shell command should be job submission time in the form of HH:MM:SS

Comment: I asked about what actually got executed, not what the output of it would be.

Comment: When I print output ("out"), doesn't show anything.

Comment: Sure, but what is actually the value of `cmd`?

Comment: @Kusalananda, it's the string in the triple-single-quotes, with the `%s` replaced with the value of `var`. Something like `ssh $servername /usr/local/bin/pstat $1|awk 'FNR==5 {print $9}' 123 `

Comment: @Akand, the question is, what is that `var` supposed to do? You seem to be passing as an argument to `awk`, which would take it as a filename. Though the error message you quoted seems odd, it should have a filename in there.

Comment: @ilkkachu Ok. I just didn't know the Python. Why doesn't the error message mention that integer filename? Also, why read from a file when input is coming from a pipe? Then what is `$server`? It looks like shell variable, but where does it come from?

Comment: @ilkkachu, the `var` is an integer variable (job number) passing from python. This should be replaced by `$1`. Yes, the full message is "err awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open `4863728' for reading (No such file or directory)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you have the shell run is something like this, with `1234` being a value from `var` (this is passed as argument to `sh -c`):

```
ssh $servername /usr/local/bin/pstat $1|awk 'FNR==5 {print $9}' 1234
```

There, `$1` is expanded into the first argument of the shell, but it doesn't have have any, so that disappears. `1234` is an argument to `awk`, which takes it as the name of an input file, tries to open it and fails.

I'm assuming you want the value from `var` as an argument to `pstat` instead. You have two options: either place the number where you have `$1` now, with `%s` as you did above; or use `$1`, and pass `var` as an argument to the shell that `Popen` runs.

**With `%s`:**

```
cmd=(''' ssh "$servername" /usr/local/bin/pstat '%s' | awk 'FNR==5 {print $9}' '''
      % int(var))  
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,  ... )
```

Note that this drops the variable value in the middle of the shell command, so you do need to know it doesn't contain anything dangerous. With single-quotes around it, only single-quotes will cause issues. Since you only have a number, this should be safe.

**With `$1`:**

```
cmd=(''' ssh "$servername" /usr/local/bin/pstat "$1" | awk 'FNR==5 {print $9}' ''')  
p=subprocess.Popen([cmd, "sh", str(var)], shell=True,  ... )
```

Here, we pass an array as the first argument of `Popen`, which makes it use the first array element as the command line, and the rest as arguments to the shell. (i.e. it runs `sh` with the arguments `-c`, `cmdline...`, `sh` and `1234`. The `sh` string goes to the shell's `$0`.)

This is safer than the previous in that variable value is never mixed with the code the shell runs (but note that you need the double quotes around `"$1"` for the usual reasons).

Note that you need to have `servername` set in the environment for that variable to be expanded by the shell `Popen` runs.

Comment: Thanks! They work fine. One clarification, when I execute the command in `cmd` from a separate "cmd.sh" file and then calling as `commands.getoutput(" ./cmd %s" %(var))`, works fine. The "cmd.sh" file contains `ssh $servername /usr/local/bin/pstat $1 | awk 'FNR==5 {print $9}'`. Why in this case the `awk` doesn't show problem?

Comment: @Akand, You're passing one argument to the script `./cmd.sh`, it then shows up as `$1` within the script. In the script, you also have only one argument to `awk` (the string in single quotes), not two as in your question. The arguments to the script and the arguments to a command within the script are different.